# Is a minimal Cauchy filter bounded?

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, filters, uniform-spaces

> Let $E$ be a $K$-vector space and $A, B$ two subsets of $E$.
>
> 1. We say $A$ absorbs $B$ if there is a $\alpha>0$ such that $B \subseteq \lambda A$ for all $\lambda\in K$ such that $\lambda \geq \alpha$.
> 2. A set $B$ is bounded if it is absorbed by every neighborhood of zero.
> 3. A filter $\mathfrak{F}$ is bounded if there exists a bounded set $X\in \mathfrak{F}$.
> 4. A filter $\mathfrak{F}$ on a set $A$ is a Cauchy filter if for every neighborhood $V$ of zero, there is a set $X\in \mathfrak{F}$ such that $X - X\subseteq V$, that is, $x-y\in V$ for all $x,y\in X$.
> 5. A Cauchy filter $\mathfrak{F}$ is minimal if there exists no
>    Cauchy filter coarser than $\mathfrak{F}$ and distinct from $\mathfrak{F}$. Given every Cauchy filter $\mathfrak{F}$, there exists a unique minimal Cauchy filter $\mathfrak{F}_0$ coarser then $\mathfrak{F}$.

Is a minimal Cauchy filter bounded? If it is, could you give me a reference or reason.

Comment: It would help if you could make your question more precise. Are you working on a uniform space? Could you remind us of the definition of a bounded filter?

Comment: If by *bounded filter* you mean a filter that contains a bounded set, then every Cauchy filter is bounded.

Comment: First of all, from page 135 of J. Horvath: Toplogical vector space and distribution,  not every Cauchy filter is bounded in the sense of above.

Comment: If in the $K$-vector space induced by a pseudometric,  is every Cauchy filter is bounded???